# How many official WOTC cleric spells exist in 3e / 3.5e d&d?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, cleric, dnd-3e

I am wondering just how many different spells a cleric has access to.

Since they do not need to learn spells and can cast them all, I want to know how many different 3e and 3.5e cleric spells were published in the myriad different official WOTC approved sources.

Comment: This question is likely being downvoted because it seems like you’re just outsourcing a counting exercise.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Downvoters aren’t giving 3rd Edition enough credit, if that’s the case. *Finding* everything you need to count, and eliminating duplicates, makes this an **extremely** difficult question requiring a ton of expertise. In fact, I doubt it’s actually possible. Totally reasonable to ask if there are any experts who have or would be willing to figure this out. (I’m not, and like I said, I doubt anyone is ready, willing, and able on this, but that doesn’t make it a bad question.)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Please take the [tour] and check out the [help] page. For your question, do you just mean spells that show up on the cleric list? There are some cleric domains that grant off-list spells, and there are other, more creative ways for a cleric to get spells. Please [edit] your question to clarify. Thanks, and happy gaming!

Comment: Is an estimate okay or is an exact number needed? By Wizards of the Coast-approved do you mean Wizards of the Coast-published treeware only; that plus magazines and electronic publications; that and that plus officially licensed material; or some other combination? Finally, why is this information desired? No game element, so far as I am aware, references the number of spells on a class's spell lists, for instance. If it's idle curiosity, that's kind of okay, but the site prefers to solve actual problems or future-proof against potential ones.

Comment: Do domain spells that can only be used by some obscure domain count as well? What about non-Cleric spells that can be used with Anyspell?

Comment: You need to define what sources you want to count. This is much more doable if you leave out Dragon magazie, for example. But what does "WotC approved" mean to you? (e.g. Dragonlance? Kalimdor?)

Comment: The question is reasonable enough. This is however handbook territory. I'm surprised something like this doesn't already exist. If someone does decide to make it happen, posting it as a handbook too would be a good idea.

Comment: Should that question be instead: where can I find all (the most at least) the spells for the Cleric through 3.X?  and in the question detail precise if Dragon/Dungeon magazine (official) are off limits or not.  So I guess Player Handbook for most of them, Spell compendium for extra ones, All Domains (SRD or wiki shows a lot of them) Books like complete divine will have new ones for sure. I don't know wich Dragon/Dungeon magazines but it would take some time. I guess a temporary answer could do for now and could be updated in the future?  Just a number would not benefit the community so much